# Signature providers are not valid for this recipient

Tags: docusignapi

i am trying to send an envelope to be signed via digital certificate i am receiving the following message.

```
com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException: Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code 400 with response Body: '{"errorCode":"SIGNATURE_PROVIDER_INVALID_FOR_NONSBS","message":"Signature providers are not valid for this recipient. Standards Based Signatures must be enabled for the sending account. Envelope is not configured for support of recipient signing providers"}'
```

I am trying to send an envelope to be signed via digital certificate I am receiving the following message. mine is configured as a developer. but in the company we already have a license to use DocuSign. I am developing the integration to streamline the process.

Answer (score 0):

SBS is a paid add-on.
If you are working on your sandbox you should ask your Account Manager to enable it for you with the Signature Providers you need (or the one you potentially already have on your Production account).

If you are working on your production environment and it used to work on your sandbox, same thing, you should reach out to your Account Manager.

Additionally, there is an API call to get the list of allowed Signature providers for your account (once your account is SBS enabled): https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/accounts/accountsignatureproviders/